# How can I modify my sql in firebird with add two dates where each date is from other table?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have to ask question about add date in Firebird. I don't know how to get correct result in this case: worker x has two contracts of employment, first in the period 1988-09-15 to 2000-03-16, second from 2000-03-16 to 2005-02-28, but one of this date is from another table that the second date.

```
SELECT
KP3.id_contact 
, (KP3.D2-KP3.D1) / (12*31) AS Y
, ((KP3.D2-KP3.D1) - ((KP3.D2-KP3.D1) / (12*31)) * 12 * 31) / 31 AS M
, CAST(MOD((KP3.D2-KP3.D1) - (((KP3.D2-KP3.D1) / (12*31)) * 12 * 31), 31) AS INTEGER) AS D
FROM
(SELECT
KP2.id_contact, SUM(KP2.D1) AS D1, SUM(KP2.D2) AS D2
FROM
(
SELECT
KP.id_contact, DATEDIFF(MONTH, KP.DATE_FROM, KP.DATE_TO) / 12 AS Y, CAST(MOD(DATEDIFF(MONTH, KP.DATE_FROM, KP.DATE_TO), 12) AS INTEGER) AS M 
, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM KP.DATE_FROM)*12*31+EXTRACT(MONTH FROM KP.DATE_FROM)*31+EXTRACT(DAY FROM KP.DATE_FROM) D1
, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM KP.DATE_TO)*12*31+EXTRACT(MONTH FROM KP.DATE_TO)*31+EXTRACT(DAY FROM KP.DATE_TO) D2 
FROM
KP  
) AS KP2
GROUP BY KP2.id_contact
) AS KP3
```

The result that I want to get is like this 16 years, 5 months and 3 days, because the result of first is 11 years, 6 months and 1 day, and the second result is 4 years, 11 months and 2 days. Can anyone tell me how to do this in Firebird? I have sql like this, but I don't know how I can modify this query to get result I want. 
My problem is how to change this sql to get a result of adding two datediff function date form two each other tables. This SQL query give me a result of one datediff because I run it on one table which name is for example TABLE1. But I have second table which name is TABLE2 and there is a second datediff. So I have a problem with connect this two resull from this two table and show the result which is an addition result of this two datediff. There is a insert with this two record from eachother tables.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID, ID_CONTACT, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) 
   VALUES ('1', '52', '1988-09-15', '2000-03-16'); 

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID, ID_CONTACT, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) 
   VALUES ('1', '52', '2000-03-16', '2005-02-28');
```

Now I get result from only one table in column 1 which name is Y(years) 11, column 2 which name is M(months) 6, column D(days) 2.

Please help with this problem.

Comment: Please be explicit in your problem description. You have posted a rather complex query without describing its intent and if it produces the desired result (or if it doesn't, what the actual result is and how it differs from the intended result). Also consider posting minimal DDL and INSERT statements to setup the test situation to make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, please don't add pertinent information in the comments.

Comment: Ok, sorry Mark Rotteveel I forgot about this.

Comment: please, show the tables and the data in them too. It is not necessarily to dump the WHOLE tables of course, but all the relevant data rows. And then show what the output you want to receive and what is semantic sense of that output, why this result would be correct and any other result would not be.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel look at this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd22d7/3 - MySQL can not have CTE in r/o transactions? or is it SQL fiddle thing? feel free to delete

Comment: The calculation or even definition of months and days is not going to be trivial matter.

Comment: @Steve - it can be averaged on a century span, though. For any purpose that spells timespan so casually as in years and months, accuracy is not a concern

Comment: There is one problem in your data though: the `date '2000-03-16'` belongs to BOTH contracts at once, which seems to be a self-contradiction. How specificaly then you gonna count the days?

Comment: @Arioch'The, if you want an average or rough working then the matter is simple, but it will throw up an amazing number of quirks in practice. I doubt your users will be happy when the age is calculated as (purely for example...) 0 years and 13 months, or 11 months and 32 days, or when year and month periods don't roll over on their apparent anniversaries, and similar shenanigans.

Comment: @Steve oh, come one! it is nothing different from sharding time to hours and minutes, or length to miles, feet and inches, etc. You have coefficients ordered from the largest unit to the smallest, and you do a sequence of division with remainder. So, no, "0 years 13 months" is not possible.

Comment: @Arioch'The, I'm giddy at how easy you make it sound! The 13 months is just an example of how a naive algorithm may go wrong. With miles, feet, and inches, there are fixed numbers of each of the smaller units in the larger units. With hours and minutes, there are fixed numbers. But there are not a fixed number of days in a month, or in a year, and the rules are somewhat complex. As an exercise I've spent the past hour or more analysing and writing a justifiably correct algorithm in SQL. As written - imperatively with intermediate variables rather than complex expressions - it covers 30 lines.

Comment: @Steve `there are not a fixed number of days in a month` - and here we go back again. You just can not measure a TIMESPAN in Februaries or Septembers, you can only measure them in some abstract quantitatvie months. So, I repeat, " it can be averaged on a century span" - and then you have that very fixed-length units, "month-span" or something. And that is the only meaningful approach when to estimate spans with months. And, accuracy and quality is not needed when the output user wants is "give or take a mile or two"

Comment: @Arioch'The, nobody is measuring a "timespan in Februaries". The basic issue is that people expect the years and months to increment on their respective anniversaries (and monthiversaries), and any day component to count from the monthiversary. A complicating factor is how you treat the monthiversary in cases where it doesn't exist - I treat it consistently as falling on the first day of the next month. If you only want a rough count, then you wouldn't use days at all (which is the most difficult component to calculate). If you have days, then you have to calculate them correctly.

Comment: @Steve - for practical applications only the first digit (or two if first is 1) and order of magnitude (amount of zeros) are often needed. That is why people measure in Gigabytes (often meaning Gibibbytes) not in single bits. Also tonnes (w/o specifying which of many different tonnes) rather than grams, etc. So whe na person wants output like "I want to get is like this 16 years, 5 months and 3 days" they don't really think about some real month with specific day count. They think about some virtual "average month" and "common sense" and "gut feeling". Thus,all months in this context are equal

Comment: @Arioch'The, then just use years and months! Or include a fractional month - such as `1 year(s) and around 2.7 month(s)` or `1 year(s) and around 11 week(s)`. Don't mention days if your users can't use them for doing any precise day-based counting. Your user with a YMD of 16-5-3 would reasonably expect to be able to count back exactly to his birthday, not for it to be a rough estimate. The doctor who says "you've got 6 months to live", wouldn't say "you've got 5 months and 3 days to live" if he wasn't being precise about the days.

Comment: @Arioch'The, and perhaps most importantly, if the user *does* have access to the dates in question, make sure the years and months tick over according to conventional anniversary logic - which I've articulated more in my new answer (of sorts). There is nothing that will annoy and reduce the confidence of users more, than familiar things that don't work in familiar ways.

Comment: @Steve yep, they might expect, but it will not work, not regularly at least. That is what calendar is. But people would not want to think and stress themselves in advance, so they would demand Y-M-D answer regardless. And YAGNI principle suggests it may make sense to give them it, and chances are they just would never want to calculate precise birthdays, so fears would be premature. I understand that every "undefined behavior" makes us cringe, but they would want thing simple more than accurate.

Comment: Also imagine they ask like how long it takes to grow chicken from an egg to slaughtering it for meet, and we answer like 2 months 10 days (random figures). Then they would have chickens born in February and July, and they would not re-calculate into "flat" months or days, they would just uptick both months and days. Incorrect mathematically, but they won't want to hear complications until it would really cause them real trouble. But maybe it just would never do

Comment: @steve maybe that "answer" was worth keeping. Though the topic starter seems long fled SO

Comment: @Arioch'The thanks but after further thought and research, I found that there does seem to be a reasonable way of implementing the days rigourously (albeit where new months often do not start at zero days). I also wasn't satisfied with the existing length and certain ambiguities in my answer. And since I don't have the time or inclination currently to adjust the answer or actually implement an algorithm, I decided to remove.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic re-creation of your table.
Use it as the example to your further work, or to your further explanation of what is the task you met.

Take it for the starting point.

1. AFAIR **Firebird** returns arithmetic operations like (DATE - DATE) in days, same like **PostgreSQL** but you have to check it. **MySQL** for example seems to count date in different units. **SQL Fiddle** does not support **Firebird**.
2. You just cannot correctly convert amount of days into years/months/days, because there are different years (365 or 366 days) and different months (from 28 to 31 days), so it is up to you to decide what You would consider "more or less a year" and "more or less a month" here and do the math. You may wrap the math into some **stored procedure** for example, to reuse it in different queries by `LEFT JOIN`.
3. This query uses `JOIN` so it assumes that the data records for every person-and-contact pair are present in both *table1* and *table2* and then only a single row in each table. If you have person-contact pairs that lack a row in some table, or have multiple - you might want to modify the query accordingly.
4. In particular, you might want to create a helper table, a persistent one or a `GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE`, that would accumulate records from both *table1* and *table2*, just for the purpose of summing them up. It might solve the problem of having rows in one of the tables but not in another. It might or might not solve a problem of having multiple rows in same table for same contact.

There also was a question, that topic-starter does not answer, so it remains unsolved:

> There is one problem in your data though: the date '2000-03-16' belongs to BOTH contracts at once, which seems to be a self-contradiction. How specifically then you gonna count the days?

Here below it is counted twice, unless the segment is half-open and `DATE_TO` should actually mean `DATE_AFTER`.

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bd22d/4)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table TABLE1 
(ID integer, ID_CONTACT integer, DATE_FROM date , DATE_TO date);

create table TABLE2 
(ID integer, ID_CONTACT integer, DATE_FROM date , DATE_TO date);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID, ID_CONTACT, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) 
   VALUES ('1', '52', '1988-09-15', '2000-03-16'); 

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID, ID_CONTACT, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) 
   VALUES ('1', '52', '2000-03-16', '2005-02-28');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select id, id_contact, date_to - date_from as D1 from table1 
   union all
select id, id_contact, date_to - date_from as D2 from table2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bd22d/5/0)**:

```
| id | id_contact |   d1 |
|----|------------|------|
|  1 |         52 | 4200 |
|  1 |         52 | 1810 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
with D1 as (
  select id, id_contact, date_to - date_from as D1 from table1 ),
     D2 as (
  select id, id_contact, date_to - date_from as D2 from table2 )  
Select d1.id, d2.id_contact, d1.d1 + d2.d2  
  From D1, D2 
  Where D1.id = D2.id
    and D1.id_contact = D2.id_contact
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bd22d/4/0)**:

```
| id | id_contact | ?column? |
|----|------------|----------|
|  1 |         52 |     6010 |
```

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2ecf9/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table TABLE1 
(ID integer, ID_CONTACT integer, DATE_FROM date , DATE_TO date);

create table TABLE2 
(ID integer, ID_CONTACT integer, DATE_FROM date , DATE_TO date);

create table TABLE3 
(ID integer, ID_CONTACT integer, DATE_FROM date , DATE_TO date);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID, ID_CONTACT, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) 
   VALUES ('1', '52', '1988-09-15', '2000-03-16'); 

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID, ID_CONTACT, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) 
   VALUES ('1', '52', '2000-03-16', '2005-02-28');

INSERT INTO TABLE3 SELECT * FROM TABLE1;   

INSERT INTO TABLE3 SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
```

**Query 1**:

```
Select id, id_contact, SUM( DATE_TO - DATE_FROM ) 
From TABLE3
Group By 1, 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2ecf9/1/0)**:

```
| id | id_contact |  sum |
|----|------------|------|
|  1 |         52 | 6010 |
```